# select component inside checkbox , antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm working on React project with antd and I have a checkbox component, when use mark the checkbox as checked a select options will be displayed.I'll provide my code to be clear.

```
        <Checkbox
      key={identifier}
      onClick={(e: any) => {
        setSelectedCheckbox(e.target.checked);
        console.log('test=1', e);
      }}
      name={label}
      disabled={viewAssignment}>
      {selectedCheckbox && (
        <Select
          disabled={viewAssignment}
          key={identifier2}
          onSelect={(e: any) => console.log('test=2', e)}
          defaultValue={inputValue}
          notFoundContent={
            <CustomizeRenderEmpty message={t('NOT_FOUND')} />
          }>
          <Select.Option key={'data'} name={'data'} value={'data'}>
            {'data'}
          </Select.Option>
          )
        </Select>
      )}
    </Checkbox>
```

if `selectedCheckbox` is true then the select component will be displayed, but the issue when user try to select an option `onSelect` function will not be called `onClick` will be called instead with false value  `e.target.checked` equals to false.

is there any way to have Select component inside checkbox without affecting the `onClick` function if there is any change made in select?

any suggestion will be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Does it really have to be inside the `Checkbox`?  It feels like they could be separated and your parent component could know which checkbox was checked and then could show the correct select dropdown.   If you wrap the Select with Checkbox, it's likely you'll end up with some weird likely invaild HTML that could confuse things.

Answer (score 1):

As [mr-rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657639/mr-rogers) described correct in his comment, the recommended design is to create a parent component which contains the `Checkbox` and the `Select` as **separate** components. Otherwise the `onChange` from the `Checkbox` is always called if a user trys to hit the `Select`. This is obviously wrong.

A simple example could look like this ([here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ecg87o) is the Stackblitz too):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Checkbox, Select } from 'antd';

const CheckboxDemo = () => {
  const [selectedCheckbox, setSelectedCheckbox] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        onChange={e => {
          setSelectedCheckbox(e.target.checked);
          console.log(e.target);
          console.log('test=1', e.target.checked);
        }}
        name="Test"
      >
        Test
      </Checkbox>
      {selectedCheckbox && (
        <Select
          key="2"
          style={{ width: 100 }}
          onChange={e => console.log('test=2', e)}
        >
          <Select.Option key="data1" name="data1" value="data1">
            data 1
          </Select.Option>
          <Select.Option key="data2" name="data2" value="data2">
            data 2
          </Select.Option>
        </Select>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<CheckboxDemo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```